# Why doesn't Express.js set my header?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm running Express.js 4.14.0 with TypeScript

I'm trying to set X-Frame-Options header as follows:

```
app.use(function (req: any, res: any, next: any) {
    res.set("X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN");
    next();
});
```

In my browser, I then get the following:

```
Age: ...
content-encoding: ...
Content-Length: ...
content-type: ...
date: ...
etag: ...
vary: ...
Via: ...
X-BACKEND: ...
x-powered-by: ...
```

Why doesn't X-Frame-Options display as a header?

Comment: @MichaelAlexanderMontero res.set is valid.  If you search the docs for res.set you'll see several examples.  http://expressjs.com/en/api.html

Comment: try using `res.append()`

Answer (score 1):

Where does this code exist?  Move it to be before other middleware.

Most likely cause: If something before yours calls res.send() (or similar) and completes the response, it will be too late for this middleware to add a header.

Comment: I've moved it right to the top (straight after const app = express()) but still no joy. Is it possible subsequent middleware might be interfering with my res.set?